# Nil while trying to get mutual friends Facebook with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the number of mutual friends, but to no avail:

```
func verifyUser(slot: Int) {
    let userManager = self.userManager
    var currentUserSlot = userManager.currentUserSlot

    userManager.switchToNoActiveUser()

    var behavior: FBSessionLoginBehavior = (slot == 0) ? FBSessionLoginBehavior.WithFallbackToWebView : FBSessionLoginBehavior.ForcingWebView
    var session: FBSession = userManager.switchToUserInSlot(slot)

        session.openWithBehavior(behavior, completionHandler:{(innerSession: FBSession!, status: FBSessionState, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println("Could not open session")
                userManager.switchToNoActiveUser()
            } else {
                println("Succes")
                println("Is session open: \(session.isOpen)")
                var params: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = Dictionary()
                params["fields"] = "context.fields(mutual_friends)"

                FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("me", parameters: params, HTTPMethod: "GET", completionHandler: {(connection: FBRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    println("MUTUAL: \(result)")
                })

                self.updateSession(slot)
            }
        })
 }
```

I am running this code:

```
FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("me", parameters: params,     HTTPMethod: "GET", completionHandler: {(connection: FBRequestConnection!,     result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                println("MUTUAL: \(result)")
            })
```

After the session opened successfully. But I keep getting this error: FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint 'me': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.
MUTUAL: nil

I just do not understand why, because I just opened a session successfully, so what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Thanks to @Sam I got above working, but how do I get the number of mutual friends in a more gracious way then:

`var mutualFriends: AnyObject? = (result.objectForKey("context") == nil) ? nil : result.objectForKey("context")
                            var mutualfriends2: AnyObject? = mutualFriends?.objectForKey("mutual_friends")
                            var mutualfriends3: AnyObject? = mutualfriends2?.objectForKey("summary")
                            var numberOfMutualFriends: Int? = mutualfriends3?.objectForKey("total_count") as? Int
                            println("MUTUAL: \(numberOfMutualFriends)")`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be that the `startWithGraphPath` function uses the `FBSession.activeSession()` by default. You're opening a session, but not using the newly opened session for the request.

Try adding this before calling `startWithGraphPath`:

```
FBSession.setActiveSession(innerSession)
```

Alternately, you can call `initWithSession:graphPath:parameters:HTTPMethod:` with `innerSession` if you don't want to set that as your active session. See [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBRequest/) for more information on that function.